# Converting an integral into polar form

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{2 - x^2}} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}} \ dy\ dx$$
 How to convert this into polar form as there would be 2 parts?
What is the use of limits x=0 to x=1 as i am finding no use of them in the solution

Comment: Use $x^2+y^2 = r^2$, $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $dydx = rdrd\theta$.

Comment: but as x=1 lies inside the circle there would be 2 parts, 1st in which \theta is less than 45 degrees and other between 45 to 90 degrees. how to convert first part to polar form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of integration is given by:
$$ D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq \sqrt{2-x^2}\},$$
but since:
$$ D = T\cup C, $$
$$ T = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x\leq 1,0\leq y\leq x\},$$
$$ C = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x\leq 1,x\leq y\leq \sqrt{2-x^2}\}$$
where $T$ is a triangle and $C$ is a circular sector with radius $\sqrt{2}$ and amplitude $\frac{\pi}{4}$, we have:

$$ I = \int_T \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,d\mu + \int_{C}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,d\mu $$
or:
$$I = \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{\sec \theta} \cos \theta\, r\, dr\, d\theta + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \cos \theta\, r \, dr\, d\theta,$$
or:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\frac{d\theta}{2\cos\theta}+\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\cos\theta\,d\theta =\frac{1}{2}\log(1+\sqrt{2})+1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Sketching the region of integration, you find that it consists of a sector with bounds $0 \le r \le \sqrt{2}$, $\pi/4 \le \theta \le \pi/2$ and a triangle with bounds $0 \le \theta \le \pi/4$, $0 \le r \le \sec\theta$. So your integral becomes

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{\sec \theta} \cos \theta\, r\, dr\, d\theta + \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\sqrt{2}} \cos \theta\, r \, dr\, d\theta.$$